# How can I access FormArray element values?

Tags: angular

```
<div [formGroup]="certificateForm">
<div formArrayName="certificateTextPlacements" *ngFor="let certificateTextPlacement of certificateTextPlacements().controls; let i = index;">

  <div
    [formControlName]="i"
    [ngStyle]="{
      'margin-left': certificateTextPlacement.xPos+'px',
      'margin-top': certificateTextPlacement.get('YPos').value+'px',
      'position': 'absolute',
      'font-size': '22px',
      'z-index': 10,
      'background-color': certificateTextPlacement.get('backgroundColour').value
    }"> [[ {{ certificateTextPlacement.get('name').value }} ]] </div>
</div>
```

Is there a particular method to use when looping through a FormArray to access an array items property value?

I want to access each array items property value of 'xPos', 'yPos', 'name' and 'backgroundColour'

EDIT - I fixed this by removing `[formControlName]="i"` and now `certificateTextPlacement.get('YPos').value` works

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove `[formControlName]="i"`

Use: `certificateTextPlacement.get('yPos').value` to access values

Answer (score -1):

```
<div [formGroup]="certificateForm">
 <div formArrayName="certificateTextPlacements" *ngFor="let certificateTextPlacement of certificateTextPlacements().controls; let i = index;">
  <div formGroupName="i">
    <div formControlName="controlName">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I specifically need to set ngStyle values so the above doesn't allow that